# Calling IResultFilter after IExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I registered filters like this:

```
options.Filters.Add(typeof(MyExceptionFilter));
options.Filters.Add(typeof(MyResultFilter));
```

then in ExceptionFilter I implemented `OnException()`:

```
public class MyExceptionFilter: IExceptionFilter
...
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    context.Result = CreateActionResult(context.Exception, context.ModelState);
    context.ExceptionHandled = true;            
}
```

When exception is thrown `OnException()` is executed as expected, but later I would expect that ResultFilter is called, but it isn't.

How can I use another filter after IExceptionFilter? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

[Filters Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) says the following:

> Result filters can run code immediately before and after the execution of individual action results. They run only **when the action method has executed
>   successfully**

and when you have an exception you cannot say that the action has executed
successfully as the pipeline further execution was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> context.ExceptionHandled = true;
> ```

`ExceptionContext.ExceptionHandled` will stop the propagation of the exception. Set it to `false` instead to allow the exception to continue.

Make sure you set it to `true` on the last one (ie `MyResultFilter`) though... This generally has bad code smell, but it's not 'wrong".